# Loop through object - react & firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to this kinda stuff so bear with me.

I'm receiving an object from Firebase which is structured like this:

```
{
  "news" : {
    "BBC news" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "title" : "BBC News"
    },
    "CNN News" : {
      "id" : 2,
      "title" : "CNN News"
    },
    "title" : "News"
  },
  "animals" : {
    "Horse" : {
      "id" : 3,
      "title" : "Horse"
    },
    "title" : "Animals"
  }
}
```

I'm using react and want to loop through this data and render like so:

```
News
- BBC News
- CNN News

Animals
- Horse
```

I've have managed to loop through the main titles using this code:

```
Object.values(this.state.datas).map((data, i) => <li key={i}> {data.title} </li>
```

The JSON object is assigned to the state 'datas'. Preview of what is rendered at the moment:

```
News
Animals
```

I have got the parent titles but not sure how to get the child titles as well.

Does anyone know how I go about getting the result I want? Thank you, sorry If I have used incorrect keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't manipulate your data structure, try doing something like this with your data:

```
Object.values(this.state.datas).map((data, i) => {

  // obtain the categories, i.e. bbc, cnn from the entry
  let categories = Object.keys(data);

  // pop the "title" key so it doesn't get returned
  categories.pop();

  return (
      <li>
        {data.title}
        <ul>
            {categories.map((category, i) => <li key={i}>{category}</li>)}
        </ul>
     </li>
  );
});
```

This should work fine without needing to change your data structure from Firebase. Let me know if this works! Check it out at this stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szbop7.